# Tilde char ('~') in $PATH? (e.g.: PATH='~/bin':/usr/bin:/bin)

Tags: bash, unix, path, posix

Based on my testing, `bash` is very happy with `~` in `$PATH` but `/usr/bin/which` is not. **Is there any standard (like POSIX) regarding this?**

Example:

```
[STEP 100] # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
[STEP 101] # echo $PATH
/root/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[STEP 102] # /usr/bin/which passh
/root/bin/passh
[STEP 103] # type passh
passh is /root/bin/passh
[STEP 104] # 
[STEP 105] # PATH='~/bin':/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[STEP 106] # echo $PATH
~/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[STEP 107] # /usr/bin/which passh
[STEP 108] # hash -r
[STEP 109] # hash
hash: hash table empty
[STEP 110] # type passh
passh is /root/bin/passh
[STEP 111] #
```

As we can see, in step 107 `which` cannot find `passh` any more but in step 110 `bash` can still find `passh` after I clear the hash table (`hash -r`).

Comment: I found that `env` also doesn't expand`~` -- that's a problem if a scripts starts  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` but you incorrectly have `~/venv/bin` first on your PATH because your system python will be run instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this part in `PATH` variable: `'~/bin'`

Here `~` is quoted and doesn't get expanded. This can be handled by `bash` builtin utilities like `type` but `which` is an external program that doesn't expand quoted `~`.

If you want `~` to expand then keep it outside the quotes as:

```
PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Or use `$HOME`:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin":/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: @whjm `bash` itself can interpret a literal tilde in the value of `PATH` as a shortcut for `$HOME`, but other programs (like `which`) will not.

Comment: Sorry @whjm deleting `hash` won't work. Let me edit it.

Comment: There is no need for a standard: you don't have a directory whose name, literally, is `~`. `PATH` is not special to `bash`; it is used by any program that uses `execlp` or `execvp` to execute a new program, and as such doesn't (and shouldn't) know about shell-specific shortcuts.