# Improper installation warning when trying to run aws-iam-authenticator with aws client

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

I'm getting the following warning when trying to run the `aws` client with the `aws-iam-authenticator` for kubernetes:

```
Warning: aws-iam-authenticator is not installed properly or is not in your path.
```

However, the `aws-iam-authenticator` is clearly in my path, since I can call `aws-iam-authenticator help` and it returns results:

```
$ aws-iam-authenticator help
A tool to authenticate to Kubernetes using AWS IAM credentials

Usage:
  heptio-authenticator-aws [command]
...
```

Oddly enough though, `which aws-iam-authenticator` does not return successfully. So something is odd with my `PATH`.

Here is a subset of my path:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:~/work/helpers/bin:~/.rbenv/shims:...:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The `aws-iam-authenticator` is located in `~/work/helpers/bin`

Comment: FYI, `declare -p PATH` or `printf '%q\n' "$PATH"` will provide a more accurate representation of the variable's current value (though I don't think you're hitting any of the relevant special cases here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue is because I used the `~` in my `PATH`. I found [this issue and comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/136#issuecomment-417417212) that pointed me in the correct direction. Updating my `PATH` to below solved my issue:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/$HOME/work/helpers/bin:/$HOME/.rbenv/shims:...:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# Where $HOME is expanded properly
```

I think it may be best practice to prefer `$HOME` vs `~` in `PATH` exports, but I can't find anything on SO / internet to confirm or deny.

Comment: See [Tilde char ('~') in $PATH? (e.g.: PATH='~/bin':/usr/bin:/bin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704710/tilde-char-in-path-e-g-path-bin-usr-bin-bin) -- bash itself expands tildes in PATH entries, but the standard C library does not. With `$HOME` inside a double-quoted string, by contrast, it's expanded at assignment time, so no special logic at lookup time is necessary.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! As always, you're amazing!